# error - SerializableError: Error serializing props returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/menu"

Tags: typescript, database, api, express, backend

I have this problem I was hoping you guys could help me fix.. So I'm making a dashboard for my discord bot, and when I try to fetch the mutual guilds, I get a 400 status code. Can you guys help??

I'm using Next.js

error: https://sourceb.in/LRtvFKRR1t

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';
import { validateCookies } from './helpers';
import { Guild } from './types';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/api';

export const fetchMutualGuilds = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const headers = await validateCookies(context);
    console.log(headers);
    if (!headers) return { redirect: '/' };
    try {
        const { data: guilds } = await axios.get<Guild[]>(`${API_URL}/guilds`, {
            headers,
        });
        console.table(guilds);
        return { props: { guilds } };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return { redirect: '/' };
    }
```

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

export const validateCookies = (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const sessionID = ctx.req.cookies['connect.sid'];
    return sessionID ? { Cookie: `connect.sid=${sessionID}` } : false;
};
```

```
export type Guild = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    owner: boolean;
    permissions: string;
    features: string[];
};
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, NextPage } from 'next';
import { fetchMutualGuilds } from '../../Utils/api';

const MenuPage: NextPage = () => {
    return <div>hewllo</div>;
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
    return await fetchMutualGuilds(context);
}
export default MenuPage;
```

Comment: Is there more information on what exactly was not serializable? This error means you have returned unserializable data in your `props`. Your endpoint response must contain something that is not serializable, such as `undefined`, circular references, etc. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-does-getserversideprops-run (see note on JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Even tho is not the same tech, may help others and even you
Next + mongo

TL:DR; Make sure you imported the mongoPromise from wherever you have it, if you have it in the same file move it to `root/lib/mongoPromise.js`

I just solved this, it seems like it won't tell you if you don't have the import of the mongoPromise, also no need to import getServerSideProps

I discovered this because I did some testig in another page inside the same project

Even tho I made it work there whit no problems I was getting all kind of errors when I moved it to where I wanted it
Also got something saying that my getServerSideProps was not returning anything...

```
import clientPromise from "../lib/mongodb";

export default function Movies({ serverRoles }) {
  console.log(serverRoles);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Top 20 Movies of All Time</h1>
      <p>
        <small>(According to Metacritic)</small>
      </p>
      <ul>
        {serverRoles.map((role) => (
          <li>
            <h2>{role.name}</h2>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="coc">
        <label htmlFor="rol">Label yourself:</label>
        {/* <select name="rol" id="rol" ref={rol}> */}
        <select name="rol" id="rol">
          {serverRoles.map((role) => (
            // todo: use the DB's _id instead
            <option defaultValue={role.name} key={role._id}>
              {role.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("jobTest");

    const serverRoles = await db.collection("roles").find({}).toArray();

    return {
      props: { serverRoles: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serverRoles)) },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```